# how can i save multiple images into separate cells in csv?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, opencv, python

I have an issue with saving my data which are converted to np arrays.
I wanna save each image one cell of CSV with the (writerows) function but it says it should be iterable, and when I use the (writerow) function it saves all of the images without any separation.

```
for each_image in raw_data:
image_file = Image.open(each_image)
each_file_path = image_file.filename
image = cv2.imread(each_file_path)
grey_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image_from_array = Image.fromarray(grey_image)

width, height = image_from_array.size
format = image_from_array.format
mode = image_from_array.mode
img_grey = image_from_array.convert('L')

value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
value = value.flatten()
print(value)
```

this is my code and any help with saving in CSV separately would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just use newline = '' when u open your CSV file.